# Ramsey-Cass-Koopmans model/Economic Growth/Phase Diagrams

Tags: utility, euler-lagrange-equation

I haven't had to ask for your service since my second year (I'm in my third now) of University. However, after today's seminar, which was filled with equations, terminology, and more equations, I'm back again to ask for more help.

(Can I apologise, too, for presenting it in print screen form; the formuale would not appear when I copied and pasted it. I also tried to figure out how to rewrite it, but was unable to do so).

The particular question that I'm having understanding is the follows:

[image]

Thanks, Scott